How to improve pandas DF processing time on different combinations of calculated data
I got a big dataset, something like 100 K or 1 mil rows, and I got a function that makes vector calculations that take 0.03 sec. Now all my columns before the process can be the same for every iteration. I want to calculate the 2^n combinations of conditions I make. So currently it will take me 2^n * 0.03 s to run it all by looping length and run the function. Is there a better way to improve performance and run all these possibilities vectorized or parallel(not Python CPU parallel. It help by little). The only thing I think of is to create unique per iteration column and make regex calculations, but then the df will be too big.
In this example process where each processing takes 0.01ms, the output is:
Total number of combinations: 1023.
Total time to evaluate all combinations: 20.73 seconds
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
import time

# Generate a larger DataFrame with 100,000 rows
data = {
    'Height': np.random.uniform(150, 200, size=100000),
    'Weight': np.random.uniform(50, 100, size=100000),
    'Gender': np.random.choice(['Male', 'Female'], size=100000),
    'Age': np.random.randint(18, 70, size=100000)
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define vectorized functions for each condition with dynamic values
def calculate_bmi(height, weight):
    height_m = height / 100
    return weight / (height_m ** 2)

def condition_bmi(df, min_bmi, max_bmi):
    bmi = calculate_bmi(df['Height'], df['Weight'])
    return (min_bmi <= bmi) & (bmi <= max_bmi)

def condition_age(df, min_age, max_age):
    return (min_age <= df['Age']) & (df['Age'] <= max_age)

def condition_height(df, min_height, max_height):
    return (min_height <= df['Height']) & (df['Height'] <= max_height)

def condition_weight(df, min_weight, max_weight):
    return (min_weight <= df['Weight']) & (df['Weight'] <= max_weight)

def condition_gender(df, gender):
    return df['Gender'] == gender

# List of possible dynamic values for each condition (with only 2 values each)
dynamic_values = {
    'BMI is within the normal range': [(18.5, 24.9), (25.0, 29.9)],
    'Age is within the healthy range': [(18, 30), (31, 45)],
    'Height is within the normal range': [(150, 160), (161, 170)],
    'Weight is within the normal range': [(50, 60), (61, 70)],
    'Gender is specified': ['Male', 'Female']
}

# Function to create combinations of conditions with dynamic values
def create_condition_combinations(dynamic_values):
    condition_combinations = []
    for condition_name, values in dynamic_values.items():
        if isinstance(values[0], tuple):  # For range conditions
            for value in values:
                condition_combinations.append((condition_name, value))
        else:  # For categorical conditions
            for value in values:
                condition_combinations.append((condition_name, value))
    return condition_combinations

# Generate all possible combinations of conditions and dynamic values
def generate_all_combinations(condition_combinations):
    all_combinations = []
    for r in range(1, len(condition_combinations) + 1):
        for combo in combinations(condition_combinations, r):
            all_combinations.append(combo)
    return all_combinations

condition_combinations = create_condition_combinations(dynamic_values)
all_combinations = generate_all_combinations(condition_combinations)

# Calculate the total number of combinations
total_combinations = len(all_combinations)
print(f"Total number of combinations: {total_combinations}")

# Apply a combination of conditions
def evaluate_combination(df, combo):
    combined_condition = pd.Series([True] * len(df))
    for condition_name, value in combo:
        if condition_name == 'BMI is within the normal range':
            min_bmi, max_bmi = value
            combined_condition &= condition_bmi(df, min_bmi, max_bmi)
        elif condition_name == 'Age is within the healthy range':
            min_age, max_age = value
            combined_condition &= condition_age(df, min_age, max_age)
        elif condition_name == 'Height is within the normal range':
            min_height, max_height = value
            combined_condition &= condition_height(df, min_height, max_height)
        elif condition_name == 'Weight is within the normal range':
            min_weight, max_weight = value
            combined_condition &= condition_weight(df, min_weight, max_weight)
        elif condition_name == 'Gender is specified':
            gender = value
            combined_condition &= condition_gender(df, gender)
    return combined_condition

# Measure time to run all combinations
start_time = time.time()

for combo in all_combinations:
    combo_start_time = time.time()
    
    evaluate_combination(df, combo)
    
    combo_end_time = time.time()
    combo_elapsed_time = combo_end_time - combo_start_time

end_time = time.time()
total_elapsed_time = end_time - start_time

print(f"Total time to evaluate all combinations: {total_elapsed_time:.2f} seconds")


The condition in create_condition_combiniations() is superfluous, the same code is executed in each branch. The function condition_bmi() calls calculate_bmi() with the same arguments for each element of each combination, but the return value is always the same. Cache the BMI value to avoid this unnecessary calculation. I suggest you profile this code to find other opportunities for run time reduction.

Well i gave simple example because i cant share my true case, my case is there are static columns and static conditions i compute all before start running each combination calculate different column values and return different result and i want to compare at end between the results

did we answer to your question ?

generally yes Although I still strive to transform my all combinations for loop to vectorize approach

I think the best method without touching too much your code is by using polars.
When I tested your code I was at : 7.52 seconds and now I am at : 0.45 seconds
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
import time

# Generate similar data with Polars
data = {
    'Height': np.random.uniform(150, 200, size=100000),
    'Weight': np.random.uniform(50, 100, size=100000),
    'Gender': np.random.choice(['Male', 'Female'], size=100000),
    'Age': np.random.randint(18, 70, size=100000)
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)

# Define vectorized functions for each condition
def calculate_bmi(df):
    height_m = df['Height'] / 100
    return df['Weight'] / (height_m ** 2)

def condition_bmi(df, min_bmi, max_bmi):
    bmi = calculate_bmi(df)
    return df.with_columns(((bmi >= min_bmi) & (bmi <= max_bmi)).alias('bmi_condition'))

def condition_age(df, min_age, max_age):
    return df.with_columns(((df['Age'] >= min_age) & (df['Age'] <= max_age)).alias('age_condition'))

def condition_height(df, min_height, max_height):
    return df.with_columns(((df['Height'] >= min_height) & (df['Height'] <= max_height)).alias('height_condition'))

def condition_weight(df, min_weight, max_weight):
    return df.with_columns(((df['Weight'] >= min_weight) & (df['Weight'] <= max_weight)).alias('weight_condition'))

def condition_gender(df, gender):
    return df.with_columns((df['Gender'] == gender).alias('gender_condition'))

# List of possible dynamic values for each condition
dynamic_values = {
    'BMI is within the normal range': [(18.5, 24.9), (25.0, 29.9)],
    'Age is within the healthy range': [(18, 30), (31, 45)],
    'Height is within the normal range': [(150, 160), (161, 170)],
    'Weight is within the normal range': [(50, 60), (61, 70)],
    'Gender is specified': ['Male', 'Female']
}

# Generate all possible combinations of conditions with dynamic values
def create_condition_combinations(dynamic_values):
    condition_combinations = []
    for condition_name, values in dynamic_values.items():
        for value in values:
            condition_combinations.append((condition_name, value))
    return condition_combinations

condition_combinations = create_condition_combinations(dynamic_values)

# Generate all possible combinations of conditions
def generate_all_combinations(condition_combinations):
    all_combinations = []
    for r in range(1, len(condition_combinations) + 1):
        for combo in combinations(condition_combinations, r):
            all_combinations.append(combo)
    return all_combinations

all_combinations = generate_all_combinations(condition_combinations)
total_combinations = len(all_combinations)
print(f"Total number of combinations: {total_combinations}")

# Evaluate a combination of conditions
def evaluate_combination(df, combo):
    # Start with True for all rows
    df = df.with_columns(pl.lit(True).alias('combined_condition'))
    
    for condition_name, value in combo:
        if condition_name == 'BMI is within the normal range':
            min_bmi, max_bmi = value
            df = condition_bmi(df, min_bmi, max_bmi)
            df = df.with_columns((df['combined_condition'] & df['bmi_condition']).alias('combined_condition'))
        elif condition_name == 'Age is within the healthy range':
            min_age, max_age = value
            df = condition_age(df, min_age, max_age)
            df = df.with_columns((df['combined_condition'] & df['age_condition']).alias('combined_condition'))
        elif condition_name == 'Height is within the normal range':
            min_height, max_height = value
            df = condition_height(df, min_height, max_height)
            df = df.with_columns((df['combined_condition'] & df['height_condition']).alias('combined_condition'))
        elif condition_name == 'Weight is within the normal range':
            min_weight, max_weight = value
            df = condition_weight(df, min_weight, max_weight)
            df = df.with_columns((df['combined_condition'] & df['weight_condition']).alias('combined_condition'))
        elif condition_name == 'Gender is specified':
            gender = value
            df = condition_gender(df, gender)
            df = df.with_columns((df['combined_condition'] & df['gender_condition']).alias('combined_condition'))
    
    return df['combined_condition']

# Measure the time to run all combinations
start_time = time.time()

for combo in all_combinations:
    evaluate_combination(df, combo)

end_time = time.time()
total_elapsed_time = end_time - start_time

print(f"Total time to evaluate all combinations: {total_elapsed_time:.2f} seconds")



Ty, polars is better than pandas?

there are some optimisations, it depends of what u are trying to optimize

optimize running vectorized calculation * Big number of times. switching from python to other language worth a try?

@mr_robot Why port to another language? Refactoring to use polars is much simpler and results in a run time reduction of one order of magnitude. Is this improvement insufficient?

It is huge improve no doubt i plan to run another script with something like 1,000,000 iterations on something like 1mil rows+ and i want to achieve the most optimized way so i think on every direction to improve it

Rather than computing the conditions on the fly like you did,why not compute them in advance. You can also squeeze out extra performance by working directly with numpy. Also, in generate_all_combinations function, I have used extend instead of appending each combination individually.
Have a look:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
import time

# Generate a larger DataFrame with 100,000 rows
data = {
    'Height': np.random.uniform(150, 200, size=100000),
    'Weight': np.random.uniform(50, 100, size=100000),
    'Gender': np.random.choice(['Male', 'Female'], size=100000),
    'Age': np.random.randint(18, 70, size=100000)
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Precompute BMI and add it to the DataFrame
df['BMI'] = df['Weight'] / ((df['Height'] / 100) ** 2)

# List of possible dynamic values for each condition
dynamic_values = {
    'BMI is within the normal range': [(18.5, 24.9), (25.0, 29.9)],
    'Age is within the healthy range': [(18, 30), (31, 45)],
    'Height is within the normal range': [(150, 160), (161, 170)],
    'Weight is within the normal range': [(50, 60), (61, 70)],
    'Gender is specified': ['Male', 'Female']
}

# Create condition combinations
def create_condition_combinations(dynamic_values):
    condition_combinations = []
    for condition_name, values in dynamic_values.items():
        for value in values:
            condition_combinations.append((condition_name, value))
    return condition_combinations

condition_combinations = create_condition_combinations(dynamic_values)

# Generate all possible combinations
def generate_all_combinations(condition_combinations):
    all_combinations = []
    for r in range(1, len(condition_combinations) + 1):
        all_combinations.extend(combinations(condition_combinations, r))
    return all_combinations

all_combinations = generate_all_combinations(condition_combinations)

# Calculate the total number of combinations
total_combinations = len(all_combinations)
print(f"Total number of combinations: {total_combinations}")

# Precompute condition masks
condition_masks = {}

# Convert DataFrame columns to NumPy arrays for faster computations
age_array = df['Age'].values
height_array = df['Height'].values
weight_array = df['Weight'].values
gender_array = df['Gender'].values
bmi_array = df['BMI'].values

for condition_name, values in dynamic_values.items():
    for value in values:
        key = (condition_name, value)
        if condition_name == 'BMI is within the normal range':
            min_bmi, max_bmi = value
            mask = (bmi_array >= min_bmi) & (bmi_array <= max_bmi)
            condition_masks[key] = mask
        elif condition_name == 'Age is within the healthy range':
            min_age, max_age = value
            mask = (age_array >= min_age) & (age_array <= max_age)
            condition_masks[key] = mask
        elif condition_name == 'Height is within the normal range':
            min_height, max_height = value
            mask = (height_array >= min_height) & (height_array <= max_height)
            condition_masks[key] = mask
        elif condition_name == 'Weight is within the normal range':
            min_weight, max_weight = value
            mask = (weight_array >= min_weight) & (weight_array <= max_weight)
            condition_masks[key] = mask
        elif condition_name == 'Gender is specified':
            gender = value
            mask = (gender_array == gender)
            condition_masks[key] = mask

# Function to evaluate a combination of conditions
def evaluate_combination(combo):
    combined_condition = np.ones(len(df), dtype=bool)
    for condition in combo:
        mask = condition_masks[condition]
        combined_condition &= mask
    return combined_condition

# Measure time to run all combinations
start_time = time.time()

for combo in all_combinations:
    combo_start_time = time.time()
    combined_condition = evaluate_combination(combo)
    combo_end_time = time.time()
    combo_elapsed_time = combo_end_time - combo_start_time

end_time = time.time()
total_elapsed_time = end_time - start_time

print(f"Total time to evaluate all combinations: {total_elapsed_time:.2f} seconds")


Total number of combinations: 1023
Total time to evaluate all combinations: 0.02 seconds


what extend does? ya computing conditions before is good but i still need to run any combination this is my main purpose i want to improve

append adds a single item to the end of a list one at a time. extend adds all items from an iterable to the list at once. See here.

Just to add to @DataSciRookie's nice answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78993498/
You can go a little further and use more of Polars functionality instead of a "pandas style" approach.
LazyFrame
The first thing you can do is switch to use a LazyFrame.
df = pl.LazyFrame(data)

Expressions
Polars has its own dsl consisting of Expressions.
The idea being that you can build all of your logic without the need to compute anything.
>>> bmi = pl.col.Weight / ((pl.col.Height / 100) ** 2) # same as pl.col("Weight")
>>> type(bmi)
polars.expr.expr.Expr
>>> print(bmi)
[(col("Weight")) / ([(col("Height")) / (dyn int: 100)].pow([dyn int: 2]))]

If we modify the condition functions to just build expressions and return them:
def condition_bmi(min_bmi, max_bmi):
    bmi = pl.col.Weight / ((pl.col.Height / 100) ** 2)
    return bmi.is_between(min_bmi, max_bmi).alias('bmi_condition')

def condition_age(min_age, max_age):
    return pl.col.Age.is_between(min_age, max_age).alias('age_condition')

def condition_height(min_height, max_height):
    return pl.col.Height.is_between(min_height, max_height).alias('height_condition')

def condition_weight(min_weight, max_weight):
    return pl.col.Weight.is_between(min_weight, max_weight).alias('weight_condition')

def condition_gender(gender):
    return (pl.col.Gender == gender).alias('gender_condition')



.is_between() is used as an alternative to the >= & syntax.

Then inside the evaluate function, you just build a list of expressions for each combo.
def evaluate_combination(df, combo):
    conditions = []
    
    for condition_name, value in combo:
        if condition_name == 'BMI is within the normal range':
            min_bmi, max_bmi = value
            conditions.append(condition_bmi(df, min_bmi, max_bmi))
        ...


.all_horizontal() can then be used to chain all the conditions with &

    result = df.select(pl.all_horizontal(conditions).alias('combined_condition')) 
    return result


df is still a LazyFrame here, so the .select() does not compute anything.

Finally, you can use pl.collect_all() to materialize all of the dataframes in parallel on the Polars thread pool.
lfs = (evaluate_combination(df, combo) for combo in all_combinations)
dfs = pl.collect_all(lfs)

